# Not able to convert react custom hook to be a context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have a custom hook(useData) that takes query as an argument and then returns data and runtime(time to fetch the data from the API). But I need access to the runtime to my Editor component when I click on the run button. Right now what is happening is when I click on run button(inside Editor.js), it sets the query to the App component using the setter function and then it passes that query to the Table component and then calls the custom hook using that query and then table make use of that data. but I want the runtime in the Editor component, not in the Table component. I know I can call useData hook in the Editor component but my editor component gets rerender every time when we write on the editor, so It calls the useData() hook on each change.

If I create a context using this hook then I can able to access the runtime and data wherever I want.
Anyone, please help me how to convert that to context!

App.js code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./assets/output.css";
import Footer from "./components/layouts/Footer";
import Navbar from "./components/layouts/Navbar";
import Sidebar from "./components/layouts/Sidebar";
import TableSection from "./components/table/TableSection";
import Editor from "./components/editor/Editor";
const App = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [value, setValue] = useState("select * from customers");

  return (
    <>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-layout-desktop grid-rows-layout-desktop bg-gray-600 h-screen">
        <Navbar />
        <Sidebar setQuery={setQuery} setValue={setValue} />
        <Editor setQuery={setQuery} value={value} setValue={setValue} />
        {query ? <TableSection query={query} /> : null}
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Editor.js

```
import React from "react";
import AceEditor from "react-ace";
import "ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/ext-language_tools";
import "ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/mode-mysql";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-github";
import useData from "../../hooks/useData";

const Editor = ({ setQuery, value, setValue }) => {
  const { runtime } = useData();
  const onChange = (newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    var Z = value.toLowerCase().slice(value.indexOf("from") + "from".length);
    setQuery(Z.split(" ")[1]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="col-start-2 col-end-3 row-start-2 row-end-3 m-6">
      <AceEditor
        aria-label="query editor input"
        mode="mysql"
        theme="github"
        name={Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000).toString()}
        fontSize={16}
        minLines={15}
        maxLines={10}
        width="100%"
        showPrintMargin={false}
        showGutter
        placeholder="Write your Query here..."
        editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
        setOptions={{
          enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
          enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
          enableSnippets: true,
        }}
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        showLineNumbers
      />
      <div className="">
        <button
          className="bg-white text-gray-800 rounded-md font-semibold px-4 py-2 my-4"
          onClick={onSubmit}
        >
          <i className="fas fa-play"></i> Run SQL
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Editor;
```

Hook code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import alasql from "alasql";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import TABLE_NAMES from "../utils/tableNames";

const getURL = (name) =>
  `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/graphql-compose/graphql-compose-examples/master/examples/northwind/data/csv/${name}.csv`;

const useData = (tableName) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [runtime, setRuntime] = useState("");
  const convertToJson = (data) => {
    alasql
      .promise("SELECT * FROM CSV(?, {headers: false, separator:','})", [data])
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        toast.success("Query run successfully");
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        toast.error(e.message);
      });
  };
  const fetchData = (tableName) => {
    setData([]);
    const name = TABLE_NAMES.find((name) => name === tableName);
    if (name) {
      setError(false);
      fetch(getURL(tableName))
        .then((res) => res.text())
        .then((data) => convertToJson(data));
    } else {
      setError(true);
      toast.error("Please enter a valid query");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let t0 = performance.now(); //start time
    fetchData(tableName);
    let t1 = performance.now(); //end time
    setRuntime(t1 - t0);
    console.log(
      "Time taken to execute add function:" + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds"
    );
  }, [tableName]);

  return { data, runtime, error };
};

export default useData;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a context and use it wherever you want, you can create a context, and add the state in this component and pass it to the value prop in the Provider component.

See the sample code.

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";
export const UserContext = createContext({});

export interface User {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
}

export const UserProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User>();
  // you can defined more hooks at here

  return (
    // Pass the data to the value prop for sharing data
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Then wrap components with the provider function like this

```
  <UserProvider>
    <MyComponment1>
    </MyComponment1>
    <MyComponment2>
    </MyComponment2>
    <MyComponment3>
    </MyComponment3>
  </UserProvider>
```

At This time, Whatever Component in the UserProvider can access the context right now and you can use useContext hook to access the data that you pass in the value props

```
export const MyComponment1 = () => {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext<any>(UserContext);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But In my case I am using a custom hook to get the data. I want to know how to fetch data using the argument and then add to global state. How to do that?

Comment: @RishiPurwar I write a sample code to update the global state in a custom hook, [see this](https://codesandbox.io/s/update-global-state-in-a-custom-hook-elb2q?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Ok you mean UserProvider is a custom hook.

Comment: is it possible to call the hook that I made to get data and runtime and pass that data and runtime to the provider value so that all the components have acess to the values?

Comment: One more question where should I place this code? In the app.js?        export const UserProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User>();
  // you can defined more hooks at here

  return (
    // Pass the data to the value prop for sharing data
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

Comment: This context manages the global state, so you can create a folder called context and name a file UserContext.js in it.  so once a component needs user related data, you can use this context to retrieve user related data

Comment: Thanks I'll implement it!